# How can I programmatically launch chkdsk GUI window in C#?

Tags: c#

By GUI window, I mean this one: right click on the drive, select "properties", select "Tools" tab and click the "Check now".

EDIT: I don't want to launch the command line version by launching windows\system32\chkdsk.exe.
EDIT2: As for the OS version, I'd like my program to support all major Windows versions: XP/Vista/Win7

Comment: I've spent at least an hour researching this, have yet to find the answer.  I will keep looking later..

Comment: It's liable to change between major OS versions, so please specify one. Also, for Windows 7 at least it'll sometimes tell you that you have to schedule it, and if you do that it'll revert to chkdsk anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If the utility you want to launch is called "ChkDsk.exe", this C# code should work:

```
Process launchProcess = new Process(); 
launchProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ChkDsk.exe"; 
launchProcess.Start();
```